# Hibernate uso de transacciones y manejo de errores

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Me acaba de surgir un problema a la hora de insertar un producto (en este caso) en la base de datos. Estoy trabajando con el mapeo y siempre me devuelve "false". No encuentro donde puede estar el posible fallo.

Muestro las clases.

**Clase mapeo Productos:**

```
public class Productos  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private String codigoProducto;
     private Categoriasproductos categoriasproductos;
     private String nombreProducto;
     private String escala;
     private String vendedor;
     private String descripcion;
     private short unidadesStock;
     private BigDecimal precioCompra;
     private BigDecimal precioVenta;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Productos{" + "codigoProducto=" + codigoProducto + ", categoriasproductos=" + categoriasproductos + ", nombreProducto=" + nombreProducto + ", escala=" + escala + ", vendedor=" + vendedor + ", descripcion=" + descripcion + ", unidadesStock=" + unidadesStock + ", precioCompra=" + precioCompra + ", precioVenta=" + precioVenta + '}';
    }




    public Productos() {
    }

    public Productos(String codigoProducto, Categoriasproductos categoriasproductos, String nombreProducto, String escala, String vendedor, String descripcion, short unidadesStock, BigDecimal precioCompra, BigDecimal precioVenta) {
       this.codigoProducto = codigoProducto;
       this.categoriasproductos = categoriasproductos;
       this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
       this.escala = escala;
       this.vendedor = vendedor;
       this.descripcion = descripcion;
       this.unidadesStock = unidadesStock;
       this.precioCompra = precioCompra;
       this.precioVenta = precioVenta;
    }

    public String getCodigoProducto() {
        return this.codigoProducto;
    }

    public void setCodigoProducto(String codigoProducto) {
        this.codigoProducto = codigoProducto;
    }
    public Categoriasproductos getCategoriasproductos() {
        return this.categoriasproductos;
    }

    public void setCategoriasproductos(Categoriasproductos categoriasproductos) {
        this.categoriasproductos = categoriasproductos;
    }
    public String getNombreProducto() {
        return this.nombreProducto;
    }

    public void setNombreProducto(String nombreProducto) {
        this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
    }
    public String getEscala() {
        return this.escala;
    }

    public void setEscala(String escala) {
        this.escala = escala;
    }
    public String getVendedor() {
        return this.vendedor;
    }

    public void setVendedor(String vendedor) {
        this.vendedor = vendedor;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return this.descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public short getUnidadesStock() {
        return this.unidadesStock;
    }

    public void setUnidadesStock(short unidadesStock) {
        this.unidadesStock = unidadesStock;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPrecioCompra() {
        return this.precioCompra;
    }

    public void setPrecioCompra(BigDecimal precioCompra) {
        this.precioCompra = precioCompra;
    }
    public BigDecimal getPrecioVenta() {
        return this.precioVenta;
    }

    public void setPrecioVenta(BigDecimal precioVenta) {
        this.precioVenta = precioVenta;
    }


}
```

**Clase Operaciones con el método insertar:**

```
public class Operaciones {

Session sesion = null;

    public Operaciones() {
        sesion = HibernateConnector.getInstance().getSession();
    }


 public ArrayList<Productos>getProductos() { 

        ArrayList<Productos>array = new ArrayList<>(); 

        array = (ArrayList<Productos>) sesion.createQuery("from Productos").list();

        return array;


public boolean addProductos(Productos producto) { 

Transaction transaccion = null;

 try {

transaccion = sesion.beginTransaction();

            sesion.save(producto);

            transaccion.commit();

            return true;
            } catch(HibernateException e) {
                transaccion.rollback();
                return false;
            }
         }
       } 



    }
```

**Por último el main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Operaciones op = new Operaciones();

        Productos p1 = new Productos("1111111",  null, "Producto47", "1:10", "Carlos Antonio", "la novedad de nuestra tienda", new Short("2"), null, null);

        System.out.println(op.addProductos(p1));


        ArrayList<Productos>array = op.getProductos();

        for (Productos productos : array) {

            System.out.println(productos.toString());

        }
}

}
```

Siempre retorna *false*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Excepciones:** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El capturar una excepción y no tratarla correctamente es un clásico fallo de novato por el que todos pasamos:

```
try {
      transaccion = sesion.beginTransaction();
      sesion.save(producto);
      transaccion.commit();
      return true;
} catch(HibernateException e) {
      // ¿Qué error ha ocurrido?
      e.printStackTrace();
      transaccion.rollback();
      return false;
}
```

La línea que he añadido hará que en la consola de tu IDE aparezca el mensaje de error. Puede ser algo tan tonto como que ya exista un producto con el mismo identificador (no sé cual es tu clave primaria para la tabla productos).

Por cierto, la tabla la puedes llamar tanto `producto` como `productos` (singular o plural), pero puesto que cada instancia de la clase representa un único producto, el nombre correcto debería ser `Producto` y no `Productos`. Un objeto `Productos` puede dar a entender que es una *colección*, no un único elemento